# Infinite sum problem $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{40n}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am very stuck calculating this sum:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{40n}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}$$

My first guess was to take out the squares and do the product in the denominator. Like this: $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \bigg( \frac{\sqrt{40n}}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} \bigg)^2$. But I got nowhere with this approach. I also did the product with the squares but it got worse.

I really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried partial fraction decomposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With partial fraction decomposition we get a summation which telescopes:

$$S = 5\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} = 5$$

Comment: This is nuts! Thank you very much!

Comment: NB there's a shortcut to computing the partial fractions decomposition: Since the original summand is odd, so is its p.f. decomposition, which thus has the form
$$A\left(\frac{1}{(2n  - 1)^2} - \frac{1}{(2 n + 1)^2}\right) + B \left(\frac{1}{2 n - 1} + \frac{1}{2 n + 1}\right) .$$ The first and second terms decay as $O(n^{-3})$ and $O(n^{-1})$, respectively, but the original summand decays as $O(n^{-3})$, so $B = 0$.